# javascript location href changed queryString (&gt to >)

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in my page.

```
   
 <script>
        var url = "http://localhost/login.aspx?returnUrl=/ABC/abc.aspx&gt_no=1234567&code=SC";
        window.location.href = url;
    </script>
```

when i load the page, it redirect to

```
http://localhost/login.aspx?returnUrl=/ABC/abc.aspx>_no=1234567&code=SC
```

the parameter **&gt_no** changed to **>_no**

Is there any method to keep **&gt_no** remain unchange after redirect?

It is not allow to use other parameter name insteand of **&gt_no** in my project.

The problem not just happen in localhost.

Thanks!

Comment: How about not having the `gt_no` parameter as the first one? :)

Comment: You cannot control Google

Comment: no one can, except themselves

Comment: i am not using google.com. Just an example, the browser changed &gt_no to >_no, not google.com

Comment: I have checked it. It is working fine ........

Comment: What browser are you using ?, Its working correctly

Comment: IE 7,8,9,10 . my company system can only view in IE w/o error.

Answer (score 1):

You have arrived at a situation where you have generated an HTML encoded value value even though you didn't mean to :)

`&gt` is the HTML encoded value for the *greater than* character - `>`. You could try make sure that your `gt_no` parameter is the first parameter. This way, it will not be next to the ampersand (`&`) character and won't be interpreted as a HTML encoded value.

Comment: `&gt;` is the HTML Encoded value. The URL Encoded value would be `%3E`.

Comment: @JustinNiessner -oops! You're right! Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Also that part about the position of the parameter is wrong. It wants to be the *first* parameter so it doesn't need the `&`; any parameter after the first one *does* need the `&` to indicate that it's a new parameter, not part of the previous one.

Comment: thanks. i know ?gt_no is okay. but is it no other method can handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could try URL Encoding the ampersand that is causing the issue:

```
var url = "http://localhost/login.aspx?returnUrl=/%26gt_no=1234567&code=SC";
```

Comment: That will not act as query string

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "http://www.google.com/login.aspx?    
returnUrl=/ABC/abc.aspx&amp;gt_no=1234567&code=SC";
window.location.href = url;
```